# Selecting an option based on the value of its data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I want to choose (aka jQuery preselect) and set the value based on data variable. The list has 3 items having same values but differing data-d.

Suppose I have variable `selectvar="d"` then it should change to 2 item in the list.

```
<select id="select2">
    <option data-id="mo" value="1" style="display: none;">1</option>
    <option data-id="d" value="1" style="">one</option>
    <option data-id="h" value="1" style="display: none;">o-ne</option>
    <option data-id="mo" value="2" style="display: none;">2</option>
    <option data-id="d" value="2" style="">two</option>
    <option data-id="h" value="2" style="display: none;">t-wo</option>
    <option data-id="mo" value="3" style="display: none;">3</option>
    <option data-id="d" value="3" style="">three</option>
    <option data-id="h" value="3" style="display: none;">t-hree</option>
</select>

val = 2
selectvar="d"
$("#select2 option[data-id='d'][value='2']").prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: What is the meaning of _then it should change to 2 item in the list_???

Comment: There are 3 items, all having same value. But text is different. There is also a variable selectvar. Depending on the value of selectvar select we have to choose which of 1 or one or o-ne.In example selectvar has "d" that's why after running the code it should select one but not 1 or o-ne. What should be the right code?

Comment: @CodeGuy, I think the idea is that only one set of the 3 equal values is displayed (see the `display-none` in the style attribute.) I think he should have 3 different `<select>` tags, however.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use below code and give id to your select.

```
$("#select2 option[data-id='" + selectvar + "']").prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: Earlier I understood something else. This is working fine. I tried.

Comment: @CodeGuy accept the answer if it is working fine for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140210/discussion-between-sumit-gulati-and-code-guy).

Answer (score 3):

Set the selected variable - then iterate over teh select list options and compare the data attribute - it the same - set selected property.

```js
var selectvar = "d";


 $("#select2 option").each(function(){
     var id= $(this).attr('data-id');
    if(id === selectvar){ 
      $(this).prop('selected',true);
    }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select2">
  <option data-id="mo" value="1">1</option>
  <option data-id="d" value="2" >one</option>
  <option data-id="h" value="3">o-ne</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can't select more than one item in a `<select>`, right? That code doesn't make sense, you should search for `selectvar` using a jQuery filter instead.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var selectVal = $("input").val();
  
  $('[data-id="' + selectVal + '"]').prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option data-id="mo" value="1" style="display: none;">1</option>
  <option data-id="d" value="1" style="">one</option>
  <option data-id="h" value="1">o-ne</option>
</select>
Data-id:<input/> <button>Change</button>
```