# How to check if select tags option exists with data attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery

So I want to be able to check if the select tag option exists. But I want to be able to use the data attribute. I have tried everything I could find with no luck. Here is my code:

```
if ($("#first-select option[data-id='G']").length > 0) {

//set the option to "selected"

}
```

Also when this is done, i want to be able to set that option tag to selected. What am I missing here? I did try `attr('data-id')` and also `.data("id")`. No luck.

For testing, I used console log to post a true if the above statement is true but it always gives me false.

**Edit:** What I really want to do is execute the code when an ajax successfully executes. So here is the code with the ajax I currently have:

```
success: function(data) {

                $("#name").val(data.title);

                var sEl = $("#first-select option[data-id='G']");
                if (sEl.length > 0) {
                    sEl.attr("selected", true);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('doesnt exist!');
                }
            }
```

HTML:

```
 <select name="rating" id="first-select">
                        <option value="2" data-id="PG3">PG3</option>
                        <option value="3" data-id="PG-13">PG-13</option>
                        <option value="4" data-id="R">R</option>
                        <option value="1" data-id="G">G</option>
                        <option value="5" data-id="NC-17">NC-17</option>
 </select>
```

The thing is that I will be using `data.rated` to get the rated value (which maybe PG, PG-13, R and so on) and if the rated value exists in the select I already have, then give it selected attribute.

This still does not seem to work. It worked once and now does not seem to work.

Comment: Use `prop("selected", true)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting a option based on the value of its data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289551/selecting-a-option-based-on-the-value-of-its-data-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are just trying to select the option where `data-id` matches the rating returned in your dataset. Seems like all you need is something like this (the data variable is just there as a placeholder for the data returned from your ajax request).

```js
const data = {title: 'A movie', rated: 'G'}

$('#first-select [data-id="' + data.rated + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<select name="rating" id="first-select">
  <option value="2" data-id="PG3">PG3</option>
  <option value="3" data-id="PG-13">PG-13</option>
  <option value="4" data-id="R">R</option>
  <option value="1" data-id="G">G</option>
  <option value="5" data-id="NC-17">NC-17</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

An example of how to handle multiselect:

```js
const data = {title: 'A movie', rated: 'G,PG3,PG-13'}
const ratings = data.rated.split(',');

$.each(ratings, (index, rating) => {
  $('#first-select [data-id="' + rating + '"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<select name="rating" id="first-select" multiple>
  <option value="2" data-id="PG3">PG3</option>
  <option value="3" data-id="PG-13">PG-13</option>
  <option value="4" data-id="R">R</option>
  <option value="1" data-id="G">G</option>
  <option value="5" data-id="NC-17">NC-17</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am so sorry I forgot to mention that I was using select2. I just realized that select2 has its own data attribute so it removes my data-id. Solved the issue by removing select2. Did not exactly need it because I am taking details from an API so it will auto-fill in all the details. But just out of curiosity (if you could point me to the right direction) how would I set a selected on select2 with the same setup as above?

Comment: And what about a multi select? if i had `const data = {title: 'A movie', rated: 'G, PG3, PG13'}` How would I tell the multi select to choose from the existing data if it matches the above JSON 'rated'?

Comment: For multiselect you would need to add the `multiple` attribute to the `select` element, then you would parse the "rated" data and iterate to select multiple options (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966260/jquery-multiselect-set-a-value-as-selected-in-the-multiselect-dropdown) for an example).

Comment: I only have passing familiarity with select2, but according to [the select2 docs](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items) you would need to first get the `value` of the `option` matching the rating from your data and then trigger the selection. If the value were "1", then it would look like `$('#first-select').val('1')` followed by `$('#first-select').trigger('change')`

Comment: Here is the updated code.

`$.each(data.genre.split(','), function(index, element){
                        $('.multi-selector').find('option[data-id="'+ element +'"]').attr('Selected', 'Selected');
                    });`

This only seemed to take the first one and checked it only.

Comment: Added a `multiselect` example to the answer that should help

Comment: Ok so apparently the space does matter. I was still getting one result. Then I realized that the separator had spaces so I did this. `split(', ')`. Entered a space and now it works. Thanks a bunch. +1 (cant exactly give an up vote because I am new to stackoverflow)