# How to set the value and marked selected of a select box with data-title using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

I want to set and select the value of a select box using jQuery.

My sample select box is here.

```
<select name="states">
   <option value="">Please select a region, state or province.</option>
   <option data-title="Abu Dhabi" value="1109">Abu Dhabi</option>
   <option data-title="Ajman" value="1113">Ajman</option>
   <option data-title="Dubai" value="1108">Dubai</option>
   <option data-title="Fujairah" value="1111">Fujairah</option>
   <option data-title="Ras Al Khaimah" value="1110">Ras Al Khaimah</option>
   <option data-title="Sharjah" value="1112">Sharjah</option>
   <option data-title="Umm Al Quwain" value="1114">Umm Al Quwain</option>
</select>
```

I am getting the **data-title** value from an Google Map address picker. I want to auto select the select box using this data-title attribute using jQuery.

Comment: Your question is unclear and lacks details. What have you tried? What didn't work? Have you searched for similar questions?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289551/selecting-an-option-based-on-the-value-of-its-data-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select[name="states"] option[data-title="'+selectedOption+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```